# Как сделать чтоб сразу при старте телеграм бота открывались кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть такой код. При старте телеграм бота надо ввести /2 чтобы открылись инлайн кнопки. Как сделать чтоб сразу при старте открывались кнопки?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['2'])
async def process_command_2(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)

inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Первая кнопка!', callback_data='button1')
inline_kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(inline_btn_1)

inline_kb_full = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(inline_btn_1)
inline_kb_full.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Вторая кнопка', callback_data='btn2'))
inline_btn_3 = InlineKeyboardButton('кнопка 3', callback_data='btn3')
inline_btn_4 = InlineKeyboardButton('кнопка 4', callback_data='btn4')
inline_btn_5 = InlineKeyboardButton('кнопка 5', callback_data='btn5')
inline_kb_full.add(inline_btn_3, inline_btn_4, inline_btn_5)
inline_kb_full.row(inline_btn_3, inline_btn_4, inline_btn_5)
inline_kb_full.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("query=''", switch_inline_query=''))
inline_kb_full.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("query='qwerty'", switch_inline_query='qwerty'))
inline_kb_full.insert(InlineKeyboardButton("Inline в этом же чате", switch_inline_query_current_chat='wasd'))
inline_kb_full.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Связаться с оператором', url='https://t.me/joinchat/94dUcaIUwQA3NDI6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно отправлять сообщения с этим кнопками, либо изменить прелыдущее.
По-другому никак

Comment: В том и дело, там есть сообщение НАЖМИТЕ ОДНУ ИЗ КНОПОК измененное и отправляемое вместе с кнопками

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение, может кому надо:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Нажмите любую кнопку", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]